# Getting the the Latitude and Longitude by Android Google API

Tags: android, google-api, location, android-sdk-tools, android-googleapiclient

I want to create an android app that can gives me the Latitude and Longitude each period of time. I read about the new Android APIs and how to get the last location but I still don't know how to use it. I tried to use Google API to get the last location but it dose not work. here is my code:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
 implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        Log.d("mLatitudeText", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        Log.d("mLatitudeText", String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));

    }
}




@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}
can you please tell me what is the best way to use the google api and Are there any another API that can give me the location.
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use `GeoCoder` to get `LatLng` from name of place.

Comment: Thank you very much. can you please give an example who to use it.

Answer (score 0):

first include this in your gradle app
under dependencies

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

then the imports are follows

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class OffersFragment extends Fragment {
  GoogleMap map;
    LatLngBounds visibleLatLngBounds;
    LatLng coordinate;
    int distanceAway = 5000;
public OffersFragment(){}
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_offers, container, false);


        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());

        realm = Realm.getInstance(getActivity());

        setupMap(savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new WrappingLinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.color_primary, R.color.color_accent);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshOffers();
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> kmArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this.getContext(), R.array.string_array_kilometers_away,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        kmArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        kmRangeSpinner.setAdapter(kmArrayAdapter);

        kmRangeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                map.clear();
                if (coordinate != null) {
                    if (id == 0) setDistanceAway(5000);
                    else if (id == 1) setDistanceAway(10000);
                    else if (id == 2) setDistanceAway(20000);
                    else if (id == 3) setDistanceAway(50000);
                    else if (id == 4) setDistanceAway(200000);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                int id = parent.getId();

                if (id == 0) setDistanceAway(5000);
                else if (id == 1) setDistanceAway(10000);
                else if (id == 2) setDistanceAway(20000);
                else if (id == 3) setDistanceAway(50000);
                else if (id == 4) setDistanceAway(200000);
            }
        });

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> categoriesAdapter = ArrayAdapter
                .createFromResource(this.getContext(), R.array.string_array_offer_categories,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        categoriesAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        categoriesSpinner.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);

        categoriesSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(visibleLatLngBounds!=null){
                    try {
                        map.clear();
                        loadOffers();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        // Check if device supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
        if (!beaconManager.hasBluetooth()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        // If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
        if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Open Bluetooth Low Energy to discover exclusive offers", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Discover", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivity(enableBtIntent);
                }
            }).show();
        }
    }

    private void setupMap(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);

        map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
                visibleLatLngBounds = map.getProjection()
                        .getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                if (visibleLatLngBounds != null) {
                    try {
                        loadOffers();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                visibleLatLngBounds = map.getProjection()
                        .getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
                if (visibleLatLngBounds != null) {
                    try {
                        loadOffers();
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                double lat =  location.getLatitude();
                double lng = location.getLongitude();
                coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
                animateToLocation(coordinate, getDistanceAway());
                map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
            }
        });

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
        else{
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        if (locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)!=null){
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            double lat =  location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
            animateToLocation(coordinate, getDistanceAway());
        }

        else{
            //Zoom in to Nairobi
            coordinate = new LatLng(-1.277001, 36.816498);
            animateToLocation(coordinate, getDistanceAway());
        }


//        Marker galleria = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(GALLERIA)
//                .title("Safaricom Shop, Galleria"));
//
//        Marker westgate = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(WESTGATE)
//                .title("Safaricom Shop, Westgate"));


    }

    public void loadOffers() throws ParseException {

        RealmResults<Offer> offers;

        if(categoriesSpinner.getSelectedItemId()==0){
            offers = realm.where(Offer.class).between(Offer.VARIABLE_LATITUDE,visibleLatLngBounds.southwest.latitude,visibleLatLngBounds.northeast.latitude).between(Offer.VARIABLE_LONGITUDE, visibleLatLngBounds.southwest.longitude, visibleLatLngBounds.northeast.longitude).findAll();
        }
        else {
            offers = realm.where(Offer.class).between(Offer.VARIABLE_LATITUDE,visibleLatLngBounds.southwest.latitude,visibleLatLngBounds.northeast.latitude).between(Offer.VARIABLE_LONGITUDE, visibleLatLngBounds.southwest.longitude, visibleLatLngBounds.northeast.longitude).equalTo(Offer.VARIABLE_CATEGORY,categoriesSpinner.getSelectedItemId()).findAll();
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "NorthEast latlng:"+visibleLatLngBounds.northeast.latitude+" "+visibleLatLngBounds.northeast.longitude+"SouthWest latlng:"+visibleLatLngBounds.southwest.latitude+" "+visibleLatLngBounds.southwest.longitude);
        offersAdapter = new OffersAdapter(getActivity(), offers);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(offersAdapter);

        for(Offer offer: offers){
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(offer.getStore().getLatitude(), offer.getStore().getLongitude())).title(offer.getStore().getName()));
        }

    }
    public void refreshOffers(){

        String urlJsonArray = "************/viewjsonshopoffers.php";
        request = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArray,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.toString());
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        try {

                            realm.beginTransaction();

                            realm.clear(Offer.class);

                            realm.commitTransaction();

                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject jsonResponse = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                                int storeId = jsonResponse.getInt("shop_id");
                                String storeName = jsonResponse.getString("shop_name");
                                String storeStreetName = jsonResponse.getString("shop_streetname");
                                String storeStreetDesc = jsonResponse.getString("shop_streetdesc");
                                String storeCity = jsonResponse.getString("shop_city");
                                double storeLatitude = jsonResponse.getDouble("shop_latitude");
                                double storeLongitude = jsonResponse.getDouble("shop_longitude");

                                Store store = new Store(storeId, storeName, storeStreetName, storeStreetDesc, storeCity, storeLatitude, storeLongitude);

                                int offerId = jsonResponse.getInt("offer_id");
                                String offerName = jsonResponse.getString("offer_name");
                                String offerPriceDescription = jsonResponse.getString("offer_string_price_description");
                                int offerPrice = jsonResponse.getInt("offer_int_price");
                                String offerDescription = jsonResponse.getString("offer_description");
                                String offerNotificationMessage = jsonResponse.getString("offer_notification_message");
                                Date offerDateDue = DateUtils.getDateInMillis(jsonResponse.getString("offer_datedue"));
                                int offerKeyword = jsonResponse.getInt("offer_keyword");
                                int offerBeaconMajor = jsonResponse.getInt("offer_beacon_major");
                                String offerImageUrl = jsonResponse.getString("offer_url");

                                Offer offer = new Offer(offerId, offerName, offerPriceDescription, offerPrice, offerDescription, offerNotificationMessage, offerDateDue, store, offerKeyword, offerBeaconMajor, offerImageUrl);

                                realm.beginTransaction();

                                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(offer);

                                realm.commitTransaction();

                                map.clear();

                                loadOffers();

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(LOG_TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                error.printStackTrace();
            }

        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request, LOG_TAG);
    }

    private void animateToLocation(LatLng coordinate, int meters) {
        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        if(getActivity().getWindowManager()!=null){
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            int metersRecalculate = meters *10;

            double equatorLength = 40075004; // in meters
            double widthInPixels = width;
            double metersPerPixel = equatorLength / 256;
            int zoomLevel = 1;
            while ((metersPerPixel * widthInPixels) > metersRecalculate) {
                metersPerPixel /= 2;
                ++zoomLevel;
            }

            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, zoomLevel);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (permissions.length == 1 &&
                    permissions[0] == Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            } else {
                // Permission was denied. Display an error message.
            }

        }
    }

    public int getDistanceAway() {
        return distanceAway;
    }

    public void setDistanceAway(int distanceAway) {
        this.distanceAway = distanceAway;
        animateToLocation(coordinate, this.distanceAway);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
        if(request!=null){
            request.cancel();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

I have not edited much as this project has a scenario f finding the current location and requires the user to update his location as it gets the last location of the user .

For those who use Realm can also benefit in this project where realm is used with maps